# Draw2D figure with get position at offset

Tags: eclipse, text, swt, eclipse-gef

I am looking for a way to get the position coordinates for an offset of a Draw2D TextFlow. For example SWT's StyledText supports that directly (getLocationAtOffset), but none of the Draw2D text figures supports this. Any ideas how I could calculate the position with the given methods of TextFlow?

Regards,
Kai

Answer (score 0):

You can try TextUtilities#getTextExtents.